# dockerfile nextjs cannot find production build

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, next.js

I'm testing a production dockerfile, however, I'm getting the following error.

```
Error: Could not find a production build in the '/app/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server.
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -u 1001 -S nextjs

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

CMD yarn start
```

This is my output

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -p <redacted> up
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠿ <redacted> Error                                                                                                                                                            2.0s
[+] Building 15.1s (21/21) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                   
 => [internal] load build definition from dockerfile                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.38kB                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16-alpine                                                                                                                0.5s
 => [deps 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:16-alpine@sha256:28bed508446db2ee028d08e76fb47b935defa26a84986ca050d2596ea67fd506                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2.34kB                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [runner 3/9] RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [runner 4/9] RUN adduser -u 1001 -S nextjs                                                                                                                                   0.2s
 => [builder 3/5] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [deps 2/5] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [deps 3/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [deps 4/5] COPY package.json yarn.lock ./                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [deps 5/5] RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [builder 4/5] COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules                                                                                                              0.8s
 => [builder 5/5] RUN yarn build                                                                                                                                                10.9s
 => [runner 5/9] COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [runner 6/9] COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [runner 7/9] COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next                                                                                                    0.5s
 => [runner 8/9] COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules                                                                                                            0.8s
 => [runner 9/9] COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json                                                                                                            0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                           0.8s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                          0.8s
 => => writing image sha256:99212e7c2f8f8c3e5b247196b5ccdabbe23f7e1ed5d30d4bf4fe063f5eab4bda                                                                                     0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/<redacted>                                                                                                                                  0.0s
[+] Running 2/1
 ⠿ Network <redacted>_default  Created                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 ⠿ Container app                 Created                                                                                                                                         0.0s
Attaching to app
app  | yarn run v1.22.18
app  | $ next start
app  | ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
app  | Error: Could not find a production build in the '/app/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id
app  |     at NextNodeServer.getBuildId (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:139:23)
app  |     at new Server (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:90:29)
app  |     at new NextNodeServer (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:86:9)
app  |     at NextServer.createServer (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:109:16)
app  |     at async /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:121:31
app  | error Command failed with exit code 1.
app  | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
app exited with code 1
✨  Done in 20.25s.
```

Not too sure what my error is here as it seems to copy everything over. Guessing it's down to the user, looking at other dockerfiles I have this is working, the configs are pretty identical.

**Edit**

Here is my compose file

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  <redacted>:
    image: <redacted>
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    environment:
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

**Edit #2**

Using a barebones dockerfile.dev I get the following output
[image]

Here's the `dockerfile.dev`

```
# Rebuild the source code only when needed
 FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
 # Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
 RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
 WORKDIR /app
 RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
 COPY . .

 EXPOSE 3000

 # Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
 # Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
 # Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
 ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

 ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

 CMD yarn dev
```

Comment: The error is telling you that didn't find the .next directory on /app/.next, so try to enter in the container and run the command `ls -la`, at least it shows to you the package.json or node_modules?

Comment: How are you starting the container?  (Is there a `docker run -v` option or a Compose `volumes:` block that's hiding the image's `/app` directory?)

Comment: I'm running it via `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -p <redacted>`

Comment: @YagoBiermann I've added my `docker-compose` file if that helps. I can't go into the container as it keeps crashing.

Comment: Added a second edit @DavidMaze

Comment: In fact, the Compose `volumes:` block is hiding everything that's done in the Dockerfile.  Delete that block.

Comment: @DavidMaze Now I get this `Error response from daemon: unable to find user nextjs: no matching entries in passwd file`

Answer (score 0):

Got exactly the same error, managed to get in on my local compoter got his after `ls -la`:

```
 % docker exec 0cc1de49986e ls -la

drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Nov  3 13:30 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Nov  3 13:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x    6 nextjs   nodejs        4096 Nov  3 13:30 .next
drwxr-xr-x  276 root     root         12288 Nov  3 13:30 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1313 Nov  3 13:01 package.json
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Nov  3 13:30 public
```

`ls` returns:
`node_modules  package.json  public`

Did not manage to fix it?

- i do not have volumes: as suggested so this seems not to be the problem!